# Html Label/TextboxFor methods in non-strongly typed view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible in any way to use helper methods like `Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Name)` outside of a strongly typed view? For example, I have a global helper in App_Code/MyTemplates.cshtml

```
@helper BuildInput(MyCustomObject c){

    Html.Label("LabelText","PropertyName")
    Html.Input("PropertyName","value")
}
```

I would like to be able to write some code like this:

```
@helper BuildInput(MyCustomObject c){

    Html.LabelFor(c, x=>x.Name)
    Html.TextBoxFor(c, x=>x.Name)
}
```

So I can bind to an arbitrary object. Instead of the first parameter being a lambda, which refers to the model, the first parameter could be the object I want to bind to, and the second parameter could be the binding expression.

this won't work because A). the LabelFor method is not available outside of a strongly typed view, and B). "x" automatically refers to a model.

Currently, the "For" extensions only work in a strongly typed view, and can only work with the model. I would like to be able to use these methods with an arbitrary object, not the model, in a global helper method. I still want to use these "For" extensions so I get all the benefits of refactoring and MVC's model binding.

Can someone show me how to A). do this with currently existing mvc functionality, or B). give me some guidance on alternative methods that still have all the benefits of the "For" extensions.

Comment: You have to write custom html helpers then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. However, this is not the best way for you to proceed anyways. View helpers are a horrible paradigm that someone at Microsoft should be slapped for introducing. In general, you want to stick to `HtmlHelper` extensions and/or partial views for anything you might think about using a view helper for.

Here in this scenario, you're actually best served by using an editor template, which is just a kind of special partial view. For example, with your `Name` property, you could add the following partial view:

**Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\String.cshtml**

```
@Html.Label("")
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue)
```

Then, in your view, all you need to do is:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
```

And both the label and text box will be rendered. This is by convention that `Name` is a string, so Razor will automatically look for and use a `String.cshtml` editor template in `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates` if it finds one.

There's a lot more you can do with display/editor templates. I have a couple of posts that can give you an intro:

- [Display Templates and Editor Templates for Fun and Profit*](http://cpratt.co/displaytemplates-and-editortemplates-for-fun-and-profit/)
- [Html.EditorFor and htmlAttributes](http://cpratt.co/html-editorfor-and-htmlattributes/)

Comment: `View helpers are a horrible paradigm that someone at Microsoft should be slapped for introducing`...you should backup your claims here

Comment: Fine. In MVC, Views are supposed to be logic-less. That's not always possible of course, but that's the goal. ASP.NET MVC then allows you to create entire complex functions in *views*, which firmly violates the MVC pattern. Worse, this code is not compiled until runtime, so if there's a problem, you don't fail at build, you fail live - never good (this is also another reason why view logic should be avoided in general). Finally, views are hard to test, where as a method in some class is *easy* to test.

Comment: While I think your sentiment was a bit extreme as I know many situations where view helpers are beneficial, this is the correct answer as it solves my exact problem better than I expected. I used this answer to reuse a ton of template code and it saved me from copy and paste. It's also much more elegant than the sample code I provided. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps suggesting a mild beating was extreme, but I honestly can't think of a scenario that view helpers would ever be the best way to go. Since they're essentially functions, anything you could do as a view helper could be done as a class method or extension. Since the latter is compiled, easily shared between projects, and easily tested, while the former lacks all of these, view helpers are a clear loser.